# ¿Por qué el contenido actualizado manualmente en la base de datos no se muestra actualizado en Symfony / Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, cache, doctrine

En mi aplicación web basada en Symfony (versión 7), estoy tomando información alojada en una base de datos. Uso también Doctrine para interactuar con la base de datos.

**Habiendo actualizado el contenido de una de las entradas en la base de datos directamente mediante una consulta `UPDATE` ejecutada en la consola**, se sigue mostrando el contenido antiguo cuando navego a la URL correspondiente.

He verificado en la base de datos, y el contenido está actualizado, pero no así en la web y no entiendo por qué se sigue mostrando el contenido viejo. Cabe subrayar que el problema ocurre tanto en producción como en local.

He intentado los siguientes comandos, para limpiar la caché de Doctrine:

```
bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-query --env=prod
bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-result --env=prod
bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata --env=prod
```

Y también estos, para borrar la caché de la aplicación:

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

También he intentado detener y reiniciar apache:

```
sudo apachectl stop 
sudo apachectl start
```

Todos estos comandos se ejecutan sin ningún error, pero nada cambia, sigo viendo el contenido antiguo.

El problema que describo está en el método `showByPostName()` del controlador que podrán ver más abajo. No es un problema del renderizado de la plantilla. He puesto un `dd($post);` para depurar, y me sigue mostrando el contenido viejo. En la verificación en la base de datos he verificado que el `ID` se corresponda también.

A continuación mi código:

#### Controlador

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Post;
use App\Repository\PostRepository;
use App\Entity\Subscribe;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/', name: 'homepage')]
    public function index(PostRepository $postRepository): Response
    {
        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig');
    }

    #[Route('/{post_name}', name: 'post_name')]
    public function showByPostName(string $post_name, PostRepository $postRepository): Response
    {
        $post = $postRepository->findOneBy(['post_name' => $post_name, 'post_status'=>'publish', 'post_type'=>'page']);
        if (!$post) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                'No encontrado '.$post_name
            );
        }
         return $this->render('post/index.html.twig', ['post' => $post]);
    }
}
```

#### Repositorio

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Post;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

/**
 * @extends ServiceEntityRepository<Post>
 *
 * @method Post|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method Post|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method Post[]    findAll()
 * @method Post[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class PostRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Post::class);
    }

    public function save(Post $entity, bool $flush = false): void
    {
        $this->getEntityManager()->persist($entity);

        if ($flush) {
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
        }
    }

    public function remove(Post $entity, bool $flush = false): void
    {
        $this->getEntityManager()->remove($entity);

        if ($flush) {
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Entidad

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\WpDcjqPostsRepository;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: PostRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name:"xyz_posts")]

class Post
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
    private ?string $post_content = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
    private ?string $post_title = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 200)]
    private ?string $post_name = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 20)]
    private ?string $post_status = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 20)]
    private ?string $post_type = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
    private ?string $post_excerpt = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setID(int $id): self
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPostContent(): ?string
    {
        return $this->post_content;
    }

    public function setPostContent(string $post_content): self
    {
        $this->post_content = $post_content;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPostTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->post_title;
    }

    public function setPostExcerpt(string $post_excerpt): self
    {
        $this->post_excerpt = $post_excerpt;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setPostTitle(string $post_title): self
    {
        $this->post_title = $post_title;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPostName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->post_name;
    }

    public function getPostExcerpt(): ?string
    {
        return $this->post_excerpt;
    }

    public function setPostName(string $post_name): self
    {
        $this->post_name = $post_name;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Estructura de la tabla (sólo muestro algunas columnas, por brevedad):

```
CREATE TABLE `xyz_posts` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_author` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `post_content` longtext NOT NULL,
  `post_title` text NOT NULL,
  `post_excerpt` text NOT NULL,
  `post_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'publish',
  `post_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `post_name` (`post_name`(191))
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=454 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

¿Alguien sabe el modo de poder ver el contenido actualizado?

#### Edit

También he intentando este comando:

```
php bin/console cache:pool:clear --all
```

Resultando en:

```
// Clearing all cache pools...                                                 

 // Clearing cache pool: cache.app                                              

 // Clearing cache pool: cache.system                                           

 // Clearing cache pool: cache.validator                                        

 // Clearing cache pool: cache.serializer                                       

 // Clearing cache pool: cache.property_info                                    

 // Clearing cache pool: cache.asset_mapper                                     

 // Clearing cache pool: cache.messenger.restart_workers_signal                 

 // Clearing cache pool: cache.validator_expression_language                    

 // Clearing cache pool: cache.doctrine.orm.default.result                      

 // Clearing cache pool: cache.doctrine.orm.default.query                       

 // Clearing cache pool: cache.security_expression_language                     

 // Clearing cache pool:                                                        
 // cache.security_is_granted_attribute_expression_language
```

Y el problema persiste.

Comment: ¿Probaste usando [`bin/console cache:pool:clear [pool]`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cache.html#clearing-the-cache)?

Comment: Gracias @Marcos. Intenté un `php bin/console cache:pool:clear --all` cuyo resultado he agregado al final de la pregunta. El problema persiste.

Comment: ¿Sabes si tenes redis/memcache activado? Porque otra es reiniciarlos

Comment: @Marcos no sé. ¿Cómo puedo verificarlo?

Comment: @Marcos ha sido una novatada. Tengo dos bases de datos, ambas con una tabla con el mismo nombre. Estaba actualizando en una y conectando desde la aplicación en la otra tabla. Por eso no se veían los cambios.

Comment: Jajaja, cosas que nos pasan a todos

Comment: yo tengo que borrar la carpeta de cache completamente y de forma manual para que funcione ...

Comment: haaaa eso de la tabla no me lo esperaba XD